# Why /home/.ecryptfs is missing inside dd image of LVM partition?

Tags: data-recovery, lvm, ecryptfs, dd

## Disk Copy

2 month ago I backed up the 128G HDD of an old laptop with Ubuntu 16.04 on it, using dd:

```
# sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/media/victor/blackWD/ss9backup.img conv=noerror bs=128k  status=progress
```

Then I wiped the laptop 128G HDD and changed for new laptop.

*Today, I'd like to recover my old home folder from the dd image I made from the 128 HDD of the old laptop. I'm working from my new laptop (512G HDD), with ubuntu 17.04 on it.*

## Mouting

Here is my 128G dd image stored on my external HDD (Western Digital 1TB):

```
# file /media/victor/blackWD/ss9backup.img
/media/victor/blackWD/ss9backup.img: DOS/MBR boot sector
```

I link the dd image onto loopback device:

```
# losetup --partscan --find --show /media/victor/blackWD/ss9backup.img 
/dev/loop0
```

I check all losetup:

```
# losetup --all
/dev/loop0: [2049]:26922 (/media/victor/blackWD/ss9backup.img)
```

I `fdisk` the loop0:

```
# sudo fdisk -l /dev/loop0
Disk /dev/loop0: 119,2 GiB, 128035676160 bytes, 250069680 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00026d62

Device       Boot  Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/loop0p1 *      2048    499711    497664  243M 83 Linux
/dev/loop0p2      501758 250068991 249567234  119G  5 Extended
/dev/loop0p5      501760 250068991 249567232  119G 8e Linux LVM
```

Indeed, my backed up HDD was partitioned using LVM. Here is some `blkid` details:

```
# blkid
/dev/loop0: PTUUID="00026d62" PTTYPE="dos"
/dev/loop0p1: UUID="77d30c72-6286-49b5-9954-10f7651ee5c2" TYPE="ext2" PARTUUID="00026d62-01"
/dev/loop0p5: UUID="nkDpfj-PptW-Zo21-GUPs-G6Ro-OdIT-0tFk6N" TYPE="LVM2_member" PARTUUID="00026d62-05"
/dev/nvme0n1: PTUUID="0e1db479-955c-4964-8587-823e6cb15c98" PTTYPE="gpt"
/dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="3F7E-BC4A" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="b4138b1c-f47a-4dd2-922e-c632e2712136"
/dev/nvme0n1p2: UUID="fc71fdfa-77ff-4104-95f6-6499348f2490" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="2b783871-027c-4e97-8781-cfe7c67d52bb"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="blackWD" UUID="038764D1793B8A8D" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="0008c009-01"
```

[image]

Now map the devices using `kpartx`:

```
# kpartx -a /dev/loop0
```

check result:

```
# sudo file -Ls /dev/mapper/*
/dev/mapper/control:           ERROR: cannot read `/dev/mapper/control' (Invalid argument)
/dev/mapper/loop0p1:           Linux rev 1.0 ext2 filesystem data (mounted or unclean), UUID=77d30c72-6286-49b5-9954-10f7651ee5c2
/dev/mapper/loop0p2:           DOS/MBR boot sector; partition 1 : ID=0x8e, start-CHS (0x1f,59,29), end-CHS (0x3ff,254,63), startsector 2, 249567232 sectors
/dev/mapper/loop0p5:           LVM2 PV (Linux Logical Volume Manager), UUID: nkDpfj-PptW-Zo21-GUPs-G6Ro-OdIT-0tFk6N, size: 127778422784
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root:   Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data, UUID=8b19f5a8-33e4-481f-b8d7-4a3d0f2b39f2 (needs journal recovery) (extents) (large files) (huge files)
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: data
```

Check the status of LVM partitions with `lvdisplay`:

```
# lvdisplay
--- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/ubuntu-vg/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                ubuntu-vg
  LV UUID                o20hjC-DEsi-Xtlb-z2J6-7Z1B-9tKl-4HzE17
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time ubuntu, 2014-03-29 01:34:48 +0100
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                111,29 GiB
  Current LE             28490
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:3

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/ubuntu-vg/swap_1
  LV Name                swap_1
  VG Name                ubuntu-vg
  LV UUID                qhSxpL-pZAp-DUDi-aR7R-wCy1-w5JI-XCYNIn
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time ubuntu, 2014-03-29 01:34:48 +0100
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                7,71 GiB
  Current LE             1974
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:4
```

and `vgdisplay`:

```
# vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               ubuntu-vg
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  3
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                2
  Open LV               0
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               119,00 GiB
  PE Size               4,00 MiB
  Total PE              30464
  Alloc PE / Size       30464 / 119,00 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0   
  VG UUID               1qtlsn-vTuS-xPkL-wqwP-Gxvc-LUcm-sd68LV
```

I activate the LVM partitions with `vgchange`:

```
# vgchange -a y ubuntu-vg
2 logical volume(s) in volume group "ubuntu-vg" now active
```

I mount the root partition:

```
# mount -t ext4 -o ro,noload /dev/ubuntu-vg/root /media/victor/8b19f5a8-33e4-481f-b8d7-4a3d0f2b39f2
# ls /media/victor/8b19f5a8-33e4-481f-b8d7-4a3d0f2b39f2
boot  dev  home  proc  root  run  sys  tmp  var
```

## Problem

`.ecryptfs` is missing in the mounted LVM partition:

```
/home# ls -ahl /media/victor/8b19f5a8-33e4-481f-b8d7-4a3d0f2b39f2/home/
total 12K
drwxr-xr-x  3 root   root   4,0K juin   2  2015 .
drwxr-xr-x 11 root   root   4,0K juin   2  2015 ..
dr-x------  2 victor victor 4,0K mars  29  2014 victor
```

whereas here is my current `/home` content:

```
/home# ls -ahl
total 24K
drwxr-xr-x  4 root   root   4,0K sept.  8 11:35 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 root   root   4,0K oct.  11 11:22 ..
drwxrwxr-x  3 root   root   4,0K sept.  8 11:35 .ecryptfs
drwx------ 41 victor victor  12K oct.  21 14:45 victor
```

And because this symlink didn't update:

```
# ls -ahl /media/victor/8b19f5a8-33e4-481f-b8d7-4a3d0f2b39f2/home/victor/.ecryptfs
lrwxrwxrwx 1 victor victor 32 mars  29  2014 /media/victor/8b19f5a8-33e4-481f-b8d7-4a3d0f2b39f2/home/victor/.ecryptfs -> /home/.ecryptfs/victor/.ecryptfs
```

these two output are equal:

```
# ls -ahl /media/victor/8b19f5a8-33e4-481f-b8d7-4a3d0f2b39f2/home/victor/.ecryptfs/
total 20K
drwx------ 2 victor victor 4,0K sept.  8 11:48 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 victor victor 4,0K sept.  8 11:35 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 victor victor    0 sept.  8 11:35 auto-mount
-rw-rw-r-- 1 victor victor    0 sept.  8 11:35 auto-umount
-rw------- 1 victor victor   13 sept.  8 11:35 Private.mnt
-rw------- 1 victor victor   34 sept.  8 11:35 Private.sig
-rw------- 1 victor victor   58 sept.  8 11:35 wrapped-passphrase
-rw-r--r-- 1 victor victor    0 sept.  8 11:48 .wrapped-passphrase.recorded
```

and my current home:

```
# ls -ahl /home/victor/.ecryptfs
lrwxrwxrwx 1 victor victor 32 sept.  8 11:35 /home/victor/.ecryptfs -> /home/.ecryptfs/victor/.ecryptfs
# ls -ahl /home/.ecryptfs/victor/.ecryptfs
total 20K
drwx------ 2 victor victor 4,0K sept.  8 11:48 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 victor victor 4,0K sept.  8 11:35 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 victor victor    0 sept.  8 11:35 auto-mount
-rw-rw-r-- 1 victor victor    0 sept.  8 11:35 auto-umount
-rw------- 1 victor victor   13 sept.  8 11:35 Private.mnt
-rw------- 1 victor victor   34 sept.  8 11:35 Private.sig
-rw------- 1 victor victor   58 sept.  8 11:35 wrapped-passphrase
-rw-r--r-- 1 victor victor    0 sept.  8 11:48 .wrapped-passphrase.recorded
```

**Where to look for the missing /media/victor/8b19f5a8-33e4-481f-b8d7-4a3d0f2b39f2/home/.ecryptfs ?**

## HELP WOULD BE VERY APPRECIATED!

I have some very important files and memory pictures on the dd image...

Comment: Not sure what makes you tho k this is a lvm problem. Ecryptfs wants your old Ubuntu login password to decrypt not the luks password

Comment: @Panther my old disk was not LUKS encrypted. It was only ecryptfs encrypted (home folder only)

Comment: @Panther my new disk is exactly same. Only home folder is ecryptfs encrypted. And as an aside note, both session password are identical (but this is not the problem)

Comment: @Panther I reformulated the title to "why missing /home/.ecryptfs folder" which is the root of the problem I think

Comment: It sounds like it's just missing a symlink.  But because it's a disk image, you will have a small issue making the symlink work the way you think it will, since it's all under the external media folders when you mount the image, and as symlinks don't automatically update there's no way to keep that symlink consistent.

Comment: @ThomasWard I'm not sure to get the "since it's all under the external media folders when you mount the image" ? If there is any way, I just need it consistent the time I do the backup...

Comment: @ThomasWard btw, any idea why "/media/victor/8b19f5a8-33e4-481f-b8d7-4a3d0f2b39f2/home/victor/.ecryptfs === /home/.ecryptfs/victor/.ecryptfs" ? That's super strange no ?

Comment: @Sulliwane symlinks.  The target of the symlink doesn't update, and if you have a different folder/file on your system at that location it points to that.  Symlinks aren't very useful as such.  And to answer your other comment, there's no way to 'snapshot' the symlink.  in reality, just know that the symlink points to the specific ecryptfs folder that you're actually looking for on-disk.  (Symlinks are annoying from a computer forensics perspective)

Comment: @ThomasWard Now I get your point. I updated the question to take into account your point. Which means that I have one question left now : Why there is no /media/victor/8b19f5a8-33e4-481f-b8d7-4a3d0f2b39f2/home/.ecryptfs ?